# how to run Cypress test cases written in python?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, cypress

I have a nodejs API app in docker and test cases written in Python (pytest)
Is it possible to run the set of test cases in Cypress ? I tried to look it up everywhere but this question is still unanswered to me. Of course I can use something like exec which will run some bash script.. but I have in mind that I would like to put all the .py cases in my cypress/integration folder and symply run it by npx cypress run.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly run a `pytest` test in `Cypress`.

There is, however, [an open GitHub issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25583) to enable just that. I suggest you subscribe to and comment on that issue to let the developers know you are also interested in such a solution.